# Print gives black rectangle in Octave 4 on Mac OSX El Capitan (Gnuplot 5.0.3 + aquaterm)

Tags: macos, octave

I'm using Octave 4 and GNUplot 5.0.3. I get a black rectangle in my plots whenever I use "print -deps file.eps" (does not depend on the format). Strangely enough, 3d plots (plot3()) are printable, only 2d plots give a black rectangle. The axes are shown, but not the contents.
All plots display perfectly in aquaterm, I just can't save them from a script.

P.S. I tried gnuplot 4.6.6, but that breaks the use of aquaterm for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are describing was a bug in Octave. It was only present in the version 4.0.0. If you upgrade to version 4.0.1 or later, it was already fixed. See [bug #44458](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44458) upstream.